# OData V4 attribute routing not using the right action

Tags: odata, attributerouting, odata-v4

i am experiencing a problem with attribute routing in OData V4. I have a simple Customers model class and a Controller, which has 2 Get methods. However, whenever i try to GET a specific Customer like `/Customers(7)` , it always uses the second Get method to get all customers, but never breaks into the method with the id parameter. What am i missing here? Thank you!

The controller:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.OData;
using System.Web.OData.Routing;
using API.Models;

namespace API.Controllers
{
    public class CustomersController : ODataController
    {
        private OContext db = new OContext();

        // GET: Customers(5)
        [HttpGet]
        [ODataRoute("Customers({id:int})")]
        [EnableQuery]
        public SingleResult<Customers> Get([FromODataUri] int id)
        {
            IQueryable<Customers> result = db.Customers.Where(p => p.Id == id).AsQueryable();

            return SingleResult.Create(result);
        }

        // GET: Customers
        [HttpGet]
        [ODataRoute("Customers")]
        [EnableQuery]
        public IQueryable<Customers> Get()
        {
            return db.Customers.AsQueryable();
        }
    }
}
```

The WebApiConfig:

```
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.OData.Builder;
using System.Web.OData.Extensions;
using API.Models;
using Microsoft.OData.Edm;

namespace API
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            config.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", null, GetEdmModel());
            config.EnsureInitialized();
        }

        private static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
        {
            ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
            builder.Namespace = "API.Controllers";
            builder.ContainerName = "DefaultContainer";
            builder.EntitySet<Customers>("Customers").EntityType.HasKey(c => c.Id);
            builder.EntitySet<Customers_CustomField>    ("Customers_CustomFields");
            var edmModel = builder.GetEdmModel();
            return edmModel;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It might just figure it out by itself. Try removing the `ODataRoute` attribute and rename the parameter to 'key' so: `Get([FromODataUri] int key)`. You might also have to remove the `ODataRoute` attribute from the other get function as well.

Comment: That would be the conventionel routing, i want to use the attribute routing instead

Comment: remove ":int" from the first ODataRoute

Comment: Thanks! This helped :-)